# "Круговорот подарков из бездонных сумок" - можно?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> И несмотря на сетования о жалком учительском жалованье, **круговорот
>   подарков из бездонных сумок** практически не прекращался.

Если верить словарю, то К. - [беспрерывный, периодически повторяющийся процесс](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82&all=x), но я почему-то не верю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарю верить можно: "-ворот" здесь означает (*круго-*: периодическое) "возвращение (на круги своя)". Самый известный (школьникам) круговорот - круговорот воды в природе: вода то испаряется, то проливается, то под землю уходит, питая водоёмы, и опять испаряется. В нашем случае подарки должны время от времени возвращаться в сумки, например, в виде отходов и обёрток, затем доставаться из этих же сумок целенькими. Если этого не происходит, то лучше подыскать другие слова.

Comment: Ну што те сказать? Змий коварррный.

Answer (score 1):

Круговорот отвергли, и что взамен?

А  если так:

***И несмотря на сетования о жалком учительском жалованье, поток (фейерверк) подарков из бездонных сумок был практически неистощим.***

ФЕЙЕРВЕРК, 2. чего или какой. Стремительный поток, **обилие чего-л.** Ф. слов, острот, фраз.

Comment: Шаронушка, не будь такой сурово-сурьёзной! М. б., автор возьмёт твой фейерверк, но, главное, увидит, что народ не принял круговорота.

Comment: Да я чего, я так...